# In SQLite , How to SELECT a column only if it exists in the table

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to write a query where the table will be generated dynamically for each job . And the columns will either exist or not based on input. In SQLite , i need to fetch the value of a column only if it exists otherwise null.

I tried with if & case statements using **Pragma_table_info** , but for negative scenario it is not working.

'''select
case when (select name from pragma_table_info('table_name') where name = col_name )is null
then error_message
else col_name'''
end
from table_name

This query is running if the mentioned col_name exists . But if not exists then it is throwing syntax error in else part.

**Only in select query it should be done**

Comment: Did you miss `END` at the end of the CASE expression?

Comment: sorry , here I have missed to type .Added now

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work if the table's name, the column's name and the error message are properly quoted:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN (SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('table_name') WHERE name = 'col_name') 
           IS NULL THEN 'error_message' 
         ELSE 'col_name'
       END
```

But you can do the same simpler with aggregation and `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(name), 'error_message') 
FROM pragma_table_info('table_name') 
WHERE name = 'col_name'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4eec4d3bd2bc5b5f6e5374307cc30d49).

Comment: This one is useful . But it returns the column name if it exists or else error message . That is fine.
Now I need to fetch the data in that column . How to handle it ?
This query I can use as subquery.

Comment: @Dharani.C SQLite does not support dynamic sql. You will have to do it with a programming language like Java or Python by concatenating the various parts of the sql statement. With queries like the one in my answer you can get the column names and concatenate them.

Comment: Yeah . Your query helped me . Thanks for sharing. But I am not expecting it to be dynamic . I will give the exact column name in col_name place.